# convert IP for reverse ip lookup

Tags: c, string, ip-address, reverse

I have an IP address e.g. `char *ip = "192.168.1.13"` and need to convert it into this `"13.1.168.192"`
Is there a proper possibility to that in C already or do I have to do it myself by simply making tokens and putting them together again?

Comment: I don't think there's such function for strings in general, but there is a common trick: reverse each "word" in a string (i.e. `"291.861.1.31"`), and then reverse the entire string.

Comment: IPv4 address in first place is 32 bits. This is how it represented in all socket-related functions. Maybe use `htons` and friends to change byte order?

Comment: Are you confusing reverse DNS with literally reversing an IP address?

Comment: No I need the reverse IP for the DNS query 13.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could always use `inet_pton` to convert it to binary form, making it easy to reverse, and then convert back to text with `inet_ntop`.

---

Remember that an IPv4 address is only a 32-bit unsigned integer. Swapping the bytes around of that is very easy.

Something like this:

```
const char ip[] = "192.168.0.1";
char reversed_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

in_addr_t addr;

/* Get the textual address into binary format */
inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addr);

/* Reverse the bytes in the binary address */
addr =
    ((addr & 0xff000000) >> 24) |
    ((addr & 0x00ff0000) >>  8) |
    ((addr & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) |
    ((addr & 0x000000ff) << 24);

/* And lastly get a textual representation back again */
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr, reversed_ip, sizeof(reversed_ip));
```

After this code, the variable `reversed_ip` contains the revered address as a string.

Comment: It got this so far unsigned char buf[sizeof(struct in_addr)];
  inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.13", buf); but I'm not quite sure how to reverse it now?

Answer (score 5):

```
int a,b,c,d;
char *ip = "192.168.1.13"
char ip2[16];
sscanf(ip,"%d.%d.%d.%d",&a,&b,&c,&d);
sprintf(ip2, "%d.%d.%d.%d", d, c, b, a);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char *a, char *b){
    char wk = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = wk;
}

void strpartrev(char *s, int len){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0,j=len-1; i<len/2 ;++i,--j)
        swap(s + i, s + j);
}

char *strwordrev(char *str, char delimiter){
    //str change destructively
    int sp = -1, wordlen=0;
    char stack[16], *p=str;

    while(*p){
        if(*p == delimiter){
            strpartrev(stack + sp - wordlen + 1, wordlen);
            wordlen = 0;
        } else {
            ++wordlen;
        }
        stack[++sp] = *p++;
    }
    strpartrev(stack + sp - wordlen + 1 , wordlen);
    p = str;
    do{
        *p++ = stack[sp--];
    }while(sp>=0);

    return str;
}

char *strWordRev(char *str, char delimiter){
    //str change destructively
    char *head, *tail;
    int len = strlen(str);

    head = str;
    while(tail = strchr(head, delimiter)){
        strpartrev(head, tail - head);
        head = tail + 1;
    }
    strpartrev(head, str + len - head);
    strpartrev(str, len);

    return str;
}

int main(void){
    char *ip = "192.168.1.13";
    char rip[16];

    strcpy(rip, ip);
    printf("%s\n", strWordRev(rip, '.'));//13.1.168.192

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the ip into an array and use code to reverse the array.

here's a neat array reversing bit of code i found here: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-reverse-array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n, c, d, a[100], b[100];

   printf("Enter the number of elements in array\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   printf("Enter the array elements\n");

   for (c = 0; c < n ; c++)
      scanf("%d", &a[c]);

   /*
    * Copying elements into array b starting from end of array a
    */

   for (c = n - 1, d = 0; c >= 0; c--, d++)
      b[d] = a[c];

   /*
    * Copying reversed array into original.
    * Here we are modifying original array, this is optional.
    */

   for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
      a[c] = b[c];

   printf("Reverse array is\n");

   for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
      printf("%d\n", a[c]);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to `addrinfo` with `getaddrinfo`. Specify `AI_NUMERICHOST` to prevent a DNS lookup.

```
addrinfo hint;
memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(addrinfo));
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hint.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hint.ai_family = AF_INET;
hint.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST; // prevents dns lookup

addrinfo *result = nullptr;
if (getaddrinfo(name, nullptr, &hint, &result))
    return false;

uint32_t ip;
memcpy(&ip, &result, sizeof(uint32_t));

uint32_t ipreversed = htonl(ip);

freeaddrinfo(result);
```